# Attributes in external assembly

Tags: .net, sqlite-net

I am using [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) . It uses attribute [Ignore] to skip some field during serialization.

I have class with property:

```
[Ignore]
public ObservableCollection<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
```

It works fine when I create the table:

```
_connection.CreateTableAcync<MyClass>().Wait();
```

Now I move this class to external assembly (project) and I have an error when the `sqlite-net` is trying to create table.  The error messages said that there is unknown type ObservableCollection.  Looks like the [Ignore] attribute doesn't work if the class in external assembly (project).

I am trying to debug the `sqlite-net` code.  Here is [the fragment](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L1787):

```
var ignore = p.GetCustomAttributes (typeof(IgnoreAttribute), true).Count() > 0;

if (p.CanWrite && !ignore) {
   cols.Add (new Column (p, createFlags));
}
```

I have `ignore` == false for my field with [Ignore] attribute.

I am newbie in .NET so I am not sure what to do in this case.

Are the attributes working for classes in external assemblies (project)?  If they are, is it an error in `sqlite-net` ?

Comment: Where you able to fix this? Same problem ATM

Comment: Yes, I have two projects in solution and both projects have the sqlite-net files. I have removed sqlite-net files from one of the project and it helps.

Comment: Do you mean the references or something else? I'm just new to windows dev.

Comment: How did you install sqlite-net? Using NuGet? It add references to the project and add two sqlite-net files to the project. Just remove them from one of the project.